infinte fraction for irrational powers
I am not that good at math but I want know if this is corret
$2^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1414213562373095\ldots}{10^n}}$ -----> $\sqrt[10^n]{2^{1414213562373095\ldots}}$
is this correct and equal to $2^{\sqrt{2}}$
I mean that is it ok to represent the $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ as $\sqrt[10^n]{2^{1414213562373095\ldots}}$ are they equal?
thx

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe $1414213562373095\ldots$ is ambiguous specially the $\ldots$ part.

i mean as the continuation of digits of square root

@MohamedEzuldin But there is no such real number, all real numbers are finite, you may have such numbers in the context of P-adic numbers

not as a real number as a technical real number or something like that

But I understand what you want to say, but to write it in way that it's mathematically correct:
define:
$$a_{n}=\text{the first $n$ digtis of $\sqrt{2}$ and then you question is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^{a_{n}}=2^{\sqrt{2}}$  } $$
and the answer is yes, because this is the way of defining irrational exponent

that over 10 ^ infinity or limit that goes to infinty
